# Microsoft windows 10 / office 2016 identifying or autocorrecting some but not all spelling mistakes

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word-2016, spell-check, autocorrect

this problem has been perplexing me for a while now. I have windows 10 with Office 2016 installed.

The problem:

- Most words are getting spellchecked when typed incorrectly
- Dyslexic type words ARE NOT getting flagged by Spellcheck

Examples:

- aireplane, penlic, necessaru <-- gets the red line under it
- someoen, teh, hte, anyoen, oen, apprecaite, wiht, etc. <-- have no red line below them and when you click on spell check; they don't pop up as errors

What have I done so far:

- reset and redid all the spellcheck settings
- changed the dictionary and language
- checked the custom dictionary

No success so far! please help ..

Comment: Have you inadvertently clicked on and accepted errors?  Reset Spell Check to the initial default spelling database.